# Convert a copied text content into CSV/XLS file

Tags: python

I have copied text from a website and the data is pasted as normal text in different lines.

I need to convert the data into xls format with the titles as headers

### Sample Input

```
Name
Jennifer
Roll No
1002345
Grade
A
Mobile
8976537153

Name
Alicia
Roll No
1003423
Grade
B
Mobile
9887665489
```

### Sample Output

```
--------------------------------------------
|Name     | Roll No  | Grade |  Mobile     |
--------------------------------------------
|Jennifer |  1002345 |   A   |  8976537153 |
--------------------------------------------
|Alicia   |  1003423 |   B   |  9887665489 |
--------------------------------------------
```

The output can be of xls/csv format
I am using **Python** to do this.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Yes @AMC . I am using re module to search the required keyword and unable to loop through it. I have presented the sample dataset here. But there are around 30 rows in such manner

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: Hint: Four headers. Header,Data,Header,Data,Header,Data... make use of this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose regex for data extraction OR use the below code which is simple.
Find words by splitting over `\n` and adding data to a dictionary.
Then using pandas to create a CSV

```
myText = '''
Name
Jennifer
Roll No
1002345
Grade
A
Mobile
8976537153

Name
Alicia
Roll No
1003423
Grade
B
Mobile
9887665489
'''

words = myText.split("\n")
print(words)
dictData = {'Name':[],'Roll No':[],'Grade':[],'Mobile':[]}
for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i]=="":
        continue
    elif words[i] in dictData.keys():
        dictData[words[i]].append(words[i+1])
print(dictData)
```

Using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dictData)
df.head()
df.to_csv("myFileName.csv")
```

Output

```
| | Name | Roll No | Grade | Mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jennifer | 1002345 | A | 8976537153 |
| 1 | Alicia | 1003423 | B | 9887665489 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kuldeep. Working fine now. I didn't take the dictionary that is why it failed

Answer (score 0):

If your data is clean and organized, here's a quick way to do it.

```
data = '''Name
Jennifer
Roll No
1002345
Grade
A
Mobile
8976537153

Name
Alicia
Roll No
1003423
Grade
B
Mobile
9887665489'''

heading = "Name,Roll No,Grade,Mobile\n"
rows = data.replace("\n\n", "<**>").replace("\n", ",").replace("<**>", "\n").replace("Name,", "").replace("Roll No,",
            "").replace("Grade,", "").replace("Mobile,", "")

out = heading +rows
with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    f.write(out)

print(out)
```

Output CSV file you can open in Excel:

```
Name,Roll No,Grade,Mobile
Jennifer,1002345,A,8976537153
Alicia,1003423,B,9887665489
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use collections and Pandas then you can do it in a more clean and less lines of code.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd


raw_data = \
'''Name
Jennifer
Roll No
1002345
Grade
A
Mobile
8976537153

Name
Alicia
Roll No
1003423
Grade
B
Mobile
9887665489
'''

storage = defaultdict(list)

data = [item for item in raw_data.split('\n') if item]
size = len(data) -1

# run range backwards using last-1 as key, last as value.
_ = [storage[data[i-1]].append(data[i]) for i in range(size, 0, -2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(storage)
# to csv or to whatever other format pandas supports
df.to_csv('my_data.csv', index=False)
```

Results
[image]